# Lightweight (markdown or writeroom-like) free online text editor

Tags: markdown

Is there a document hosting service, allowing editing the documents using only Markdown or just raw text?

Requirements:

- "web 2.0" interface (quick saving with a shortcut, probably Ctrl-S; also auto-saving would be great), but lightweight (Google Docs is too slow and clunky for me here),
- permanent storage (not cookie-based or lost-on-leave),
- for free,
- multiple files per user, password protected (https would be a plus),
- optional: ability to view older revisions/versions of the text would be a plus.

I've found two sites that looked very promising (for the rawtext option):

- http://www.simpletext.ws
- http://writer.bighugelabs.com

but both of them can't handle entering the "ś" character of my native language (Polish), because they intercept "AltGr+s" keyboard shortcut as a shortcut to "[S]ave file" command. So that disqualifies them as for now.

Answer (score 4):

http://hashify.me
Lightweight free markdown editor but no password protection. Doesn't seem to intercept `AltGr+S`.

http://wrttn.in/
Still no password, no interception ... and provides a button to save.

Comment: Wow, very interesting and likable markdown editor! +1! And true, it doesn't intercept "AlgGr+s" - but unfortunately, that's due to no easy save functionality: you have to remember a bit.ly address somehow each time you want to save. Plus no password, as you mentioned. So two requirements missed, pity :( although still thanks for a very worthy link :)

Comment: @akavel I added wrttn.in in my answer, so it's down to 1 requirement missed i think ;)

Comment: Neither Hashify nor Wrttn auto-scroll the preview as you type. I've posted some editors that do in [Side-by-side online markdown editor with autoscroll supporting images correctly](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/75879/side-by-side-online-markdown-editor-with-autoscroll-supporting-images-correctly).

Comment: I think wrttn is now found [here](http://wrttn.me/). It may be a different product, though.

Answer (score 1):

Try [notepad.cc](http://notepad.cc). Raw text only and you get a unique URL per file/document. You can add a password to your file too and change your URL. There is no concept of a user though. It's file-centric so you'd need to keep track of the documents on your own.

Comment: boo, also does intercept Alt+S on Windows :(  `if ((e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey) && e.keyCode == 83) { // Save`

Comment: I don't see any Markdown preview here? In the meantime, much better options have emerged - see [Side-by-side online markdown editor with autoscroll supporting images correctly](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/75879/side-by-side-online-markdown-editor-with-autoscroll-supporting-images-correctly).

Comment: @DanDascalescu
>Is there a document hosting service, allowing editing the documents using only Markdown or just raw text?

He said MarkDown or just raw text.

Answer (score 0):

Since this question was posted, some high-quality online Markdown editors have become available. They have side-by-side Markdown preview, auto-saving, and automatic sync with Google Drive, Dropbox and other cloud services.

- [StackEdit](https://stackedit.io/editor)
- [Dillinger.io](http://dillinger.io)

See more at this other question: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/75879/side-by-side-online-markdown-editor-with-autoscroll-supporting-images-correctly.

Comment: Why the downvote, if you can spare a second to comment?

Comment: Additionally, [Github Gist](http://gist.github.com), which is good for _way_ more than just Markdown sharing, but does serve that purpose quite well, [Marxico](https://marxi.co/), which strikes me as a sort of StackEdit (which I love) with Evernote integration, [MarkdownShare](http://markdownshare.com/), and [notepad.cc](http://notepad.cc/) (for plaintext sharing only) are also out there.

Comment: Additionally, I do think either StackEdit or Marxico are what the OP was looking for. Upvote.